# 2005 Honda accord. Loose handbrake

Tags: honda, accord, handbrake

I have a 2005 Honda Accord, I have noticed that the parking hand brake has no grip and is very loose. It is real easy to lift it up and there is barely no click until it gets really high up. I also noticed that rear pads are stuck to the rotor and are making a funny smell. 
Apparently, it has been grinding the pad for god knows how long. 
How can I fix that? Is it something I can do myself? I checked youtube and other resources did not find anything.

Comment: Sounds like new pads, new rotors and new handbrake cables. There are videos of changing front & rear pads on youtube and some will be relevant but may be about a different make of car but the correct make of brake...

Comment: You mean the rear brake pads, or are you talking about part of the handbrake system?